# Understanding ExtJS Framework Syntax

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, extjs

I have been given a project that uses Sencha's ExtJS framework, with no handover or documentation. I am trying to come to grips with it and understand the following syntax, and seeking sites/resources for a newcomer to this framework.

I have been going through the code and unsure exactly what it is doing, i.e.:

```
if(val==1) {
        Ext.getCmp('status').setText('AWAITING APPROV');
    }
    switch(flag) {
        case 1: if(val==0) {
                    Ext.getCmp('complex_first').el.replaceCls('x-form-complex', 'x-form-simplex');
                } else {
                    Ext.getCmp('complex_first').el.replaceCls('x-form-simplex', 'x-form-complex');
                }
                break;
        case 2: if(val==0) {
                    Ext.getCmp('complex_second').el.replaceCls('x-form-complex', 'x-form-simplex');
                } else {
                    Ext.getCmp('complex_second').el.replaceCls('x-form-simplex', 'x-form-complex');
                }
                break;
    default: break;
    }
```

Now I know jQuery quite well so can be used to compare to ExtJS but what exactly are the following doing:

1. `Ext.getCmp('status')`
2. `Ext.getCmp('complex_first').el.replaceCls('x-form-complex',
       'x-form-simplex');`
3. `Ext.getCmp('complex_first').el.replaceCls('x-form-simplex',
   'x-form-complex');`

Are these classes/div ids and is it something in the code or CSS files that will provide more info?

Comment: Could you please post in which version of Ext is your app written? It could be important. You can check it using `Ext.versions` in app console.

Answer (score 2):

In an Ext JS app, everything on the page which is a child of [Ext.Component](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.1/guides/core_concepts/components.html) (grids, panels, form items, etc) gets registered with the static [Ext.ComponentManager](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.0/modern/Ext.ComponentManager.html).

This provides a simple way to programatically retrieve references to those components and perform actions on them, without having to run potentially complex DOM queries.

Ext.getCmp() is an alias of [Ext.ComponentManager.get()](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.0/modern/Ext.ComponentManager.html#method-get) and so, in your example, Ext.getCmp('status') will retrieve the component which was created with id *status*. You'll be able to find a reference to that in the codebase.

A component, **only after being rendered**, gains an [Ext.dom.Element](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.0/modern/Ext.dom.Element.html) object, allowing you to interact with the DOM element. This can be accessed via .getEl() or, directly, the .el property. The Element object provides additional methods to interact with the DOM, provide cross-browser compliance, etc. (Broadly equivalent to the jQuery element)

[replaceCls()](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.0/modern/Ext.dom.Element.html#method-replaceCls) will swap **or add** the classes in the DOM.

I would recommend creating an example application to get a grasp of the core Ext JS concepts before attempting to decipher a potentially complex codebase.

Answer (score 1):

The [docs](http://docs.sencha.com) are good. Make sure to look for the version and toolkit that match your project. In addition to documentation, you can click "view source" at the top of the page or at the property/method level to see the source code for the class or member. In the right column it lists the class hierarchy, all the subclasses, mixins, and more.

`Ext.getCmp` looks up an [Ext.Component](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.1/classic/Ext.Component.html) by id. This returns the component instance, which is an Ext object. The strings your code is passing to this method ('status', 'complex_first', 'complex_second') should match the [`id`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.1/classic/Ext.Component.html#cfg-id) given to the component in the JS code. Also it will be the id given to the underlying DOM element when rendered.

The current version docs for Component doesn't list a property, `el`, however you'll find it if you go back to [version 3.4](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.Component-property-el). It returns an instance of [`Ext.dom.Element`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.1/classic/Ext.dom.Element.html), which is a wrapper for the top level DOM element representing the component. The currently supported way to get that is to call [`getEl`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.1/classic/Ext.Component.html#method-getEl). But if you look at the [source](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.1/classic/src/Component.js.html#Ext.Component-method-getEl) for the current version you'll see that it is returning the `.el` property. So that property is still there behind the scenes.

[`replaceCls`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.1/classic/Ext.dom.Element.html#method-replaceCls) is a method of `Ext.dom.Element` that replaces one or more CSS classes on this element with other classes.